# What are W1C and R1C register access types?

Tags: digital-logic, rtl, register-file

I drew a diagram for the W1C and R1C register access types for register file/bank. First I am trying to make a register file for different registers. I am using D-FF to store 1-bit data, but I'm confused about where I should put the logic for Write 1 to clear and read 1 to clear registers in the diagram.

First D-FF is for W1C and the second is for the RW register type. Is the logic for W1C correct or not? If not, please explain to me what the correct logic for it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For register access types, W1C means ***w***rite ***1*** to ***c***lear. Writing 0 or reading does not modify the register. Other logic will set the logic to 1.

You currently have the logic `d = rst ? 0 : (wr_en ? wdata : q)` (note names are localized). This doesn't work because writing 1 while `rst` is low will attempt to set 1, but will ignored as the flop appears to have an asynchronous active low reset. Functionally there is no way to set the flop to 1 with your implementation.

The proper W1C assigns the flop to 0 when its write enable and the data bit are 1. Depending on the priority if the hw asserting and wdata, a W1C would looks something like this (using bit-wise operators for multi-bit support):

- `d = (wr_en ? (q & ~wdata) : q) | hw_set` where hw_set has priority
- `d = wr_en ? ((q | hw_set) & ~wdata) : (q | hw_set)` where wdata has priority

R1C is a read only register that is cleared after its been read. Like the W1C, it is other logic that will set the bits. The logic is similar the W1C but I will leave it to you to figure out.

Comment: I will try to figure out the R1C. Thank you for answering.